# Binomial distribution "matix of results"

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am having trouble understanding the formal definition of the binomial distribution.
$$f(k;n,p) = \Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Or rather how I "transform" the definition to suit my needs.
I randomly conduct 100 experiments in a Java programm with the binomial distribution. The probability of success is 40%. How would I formally write that the results are stored in a vector as is:
$$(1,0,1,0,0,0,...,experiment_{100})$$

Comment: The binomial distribution is a probability distribution on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}.$ You write: "I randomly conduct 100 experiments in a Java program". What is the outcome of a single one of those 100 experiments? Is it a number in $\{1,\ldots,n\}?$ Or is it just $0$ or $1?$

Comment: The single outcome of one of these experiments is just 0 or 1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the experiments you conduct in your Java program are "independent" and put $X :=$ "number of $1$s in the vector from your question". Then $X$ is a random variables which takes values from the set $\{0,\ldots,100\}$ and is distributed according to the Binomial distribution with parameters $n = 100$ and $p = 0.4,$, i.e. $Prob(X = k) = f(k;100,0.4)$ for $k \in \{0,\ldots,100\}$ with $f(\cdots)$ as in your question.